# Курносый нос - при чем тут курица?

Tags: этимология

Вздернутый нос называют курносым. Как я понимаю, тут идет намек на курицу, точнее, куриный клюв. Но куриный клюв ни разу не загнутый кверху, наоборот, его кончик загибается вниз. Так почему тогда нос — курносый?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изначально было **карноносый**, т.е. буквально "коротконосый". Затем под действием закона гаплологии два одинаковых слога сократились в семантически непонятную **карносый**, которое в свою очередь под действием народной этимологии стало **курносым**, как у курицы.